# Custom Wordpress Page With Contact Form

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a contact form for a Wordpress site. FYI: The client wants the form to be static so they don't need to be able to change it in the future. I found this form online. I put it into my custom page in Wordpress. I also put a mail.php file on my server. When I click submit it hijacks me to my homepage/main theme page and my message is never sent. I don't understand why it takes me to the homage an how I fix this.

[image]

```
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><strong>Contact Form </strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="mail.php">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td width="16%">Subject</td>
<td width="2%">:</td>
<td width="82%"><input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Detail</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><textarea name="detail" cols="50" rows="4" id="detail"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="customer_mail" type="text" id="customer_mail" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Mail.php

```
<?php

// Contact subject
$subject ="$subject"; 

// Details
$message="$detail";

// Mail of sender
$mail_from="$customer_mail"; 

// From 
$header="from: $name <$mail_from>";

// Enter your email address
$to ='someone@somewhere.com';
$mail=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've recived your information"
if($mail){
echo "We've recived your contact information";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Comment: Is mail.php in web root? If so, try changing the form action to "/mail.php".  Even better, use one of the many wonderful contact form plugins - they will provide much better user feedback and even use AJAX.

Comment: I need the ability to FULLY customize beyond what the plugins will provide and /mail.php did not work

Comment: Where is mail.php? Have you posted the complete contents of mail.php, because what you have there definitely won't work - it does not use the contents of $_POST.

Comment: yes that is everything from mail.php

Comment: I don't think your php is at a level where you should be writing your own mail script.  Please strongly consider using a plugin.  Many are quite customizable (I like contact form 7).

Comment: they are not customizable enough

Comment: You should do some reading on 1) forms and PHP and 2) validating form data.

Comment: I tried to follow this and others: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/8.html

Comment: That tutorial is not at all correct, you need to read up on using $_POST to get form data.  And, again, on VALIDATING that data.

Comment: is there a tutorial you would recommend

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest form, it's open to injection..

```
$subject ="write something here";

// Details 
$message = "write something here";

// Mail of sender 
$mail_from = $_POST['customer_mail'];

// From 
$header="fromfrom: yourname <yourdomain@yourdomain.con>";

// Enter your email address 
$to ='$mail_from';
```

And put the rest of the code after it..

EDIT:

```
$subject = $_POST['details'];

// Mail of sender 
$mail_from = $_POST['customer_mail'];

// From 
$name = $_POST['name'];

// Details 
$message = 'E-mail sent from: '.$mail_from.'\r\nName: '.$nane.'\r\n'.$_POST['details'];

// Enter your email address 
$to ='yourdomain@yourdomain.com';

$mail=mail($to,$subject,$message);
```

FINAL EDIT:

```
  <?

if (isset($_POST['customer_mail'])) {

  $subject = $_POST['detail'];

  // Mail of sender 
  $mail_from = $_POST['customer_mail'];

  // From 
  $name = $_POST['name'];

  // Details 
  $message = 'E-mail sent from: '.$mail_from.'\r\nName: '.$name.'\r\n'.$_POST['detail'];

  // Enter your email address 
  $to ='yourdomain@yourdomain.com'; //edit this

  $mail=mail($to,$subject,$message);

  echo "Your mail has been sent";

} else {

?>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1"> 
  <tr> 
    <td><strong>Contact Form </strong></td> 
  </tr> 
</table> 

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1"> 
  <tr> 
    <td>
      <form name="form1" method="post" action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 

        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3"> 
          <tr>   
            <td width="16%">Subject</td> 
            <td width="2%">:</td> 
            <td width="82%">
              <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" size="50">
            </td> 
          </tr> 
          <tr> 
            <td>Detail</td> 
            <td>:</td> 
            <td>
              <textarea name="detail" cols="50" rows="4" id="detail"></textarea>
            </td> 
          </tr> 
          <tr> 
            <td>Name</td> 
            <td>:</td> 
            <td>
              <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="50">
            </td> 
          </tr> 
          <tr> 
            <td>Email</td> 
            <td>:</td> 
            <td>
              <input name="customer_mail" type="text" id="customer_mail" size="50">
            </td> 
          </tr> 
          <tr> 
            <td>&nbsp;</td> 
            <td>&nbsp;</td> 
            <td>
              <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> 
              <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset">
            </td> 
          </tr> 
        </table> 
      </form> 
    </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>


<?
}
?>
```

Comment: How do I use text boxes not "write something here";

Comment: write anything between `"` `"`

Comment: i need people to be able to type in a form and it to send by not editable i meant the client wouldn't be able to change the email it was sent to

Comment: I have posted an edited change yourdomain@yourdomain.com to your  address, and it should yourdomain's valid email or else the mail won't be sent..

Comment: its still not working the url says mail.php but i takes me to the home page

Comment: Do you have an htaccess file?

Comment: Ok i posted a final edit, delete mail.php and put the code where you want on index.php

Comment: it is still taking me to the homepage when i click submit

Comment: i just did it and didn't receive the email and it took me to the home page

Comment: why is it taking me to the the hompage let alone not sending it

Comment: The script will take you to homepage, and if the mail is sent it will display `Your mail sent` instead of form..

Comment: Do you have an email of your domain?

Comment: "email of your domain"?

Comment: like contact@yourdomainname.com?

Comment: i was just sending it to my gmail

Comment: You need to set it up or you can't send a mail via php atleast

Comment: You can send whatever you want, but you need an email of your domain setup

Comment: The code is right, and it's working for me, there might some other issue, here is a tutorial http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/custom-php-contact-forms/ **note: it's just a basic tutorial, your data must be filtered**

Comment: Filtered by php functions, see http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Comment: but how do I get around the filters?

Comment: First make a basic form, then try adding filter on your by reading the documentation on php.net